# How to display data retrieved from ASP.NET API into angular V13

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to get every motorcycle content from the web api and display them into my angular project.

- ASP.NET Framework Web API 4.7
- Angular CLI: 13.3.7
- Angular: 13.3.11

***Web API side:***

**Controller:**

```
    [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
    public class HomeController : ApiController
    {
        private NavEcommerceDBfirstEntities db = new NavEcommerceDBfirstEntities();

        public HomeModel Get()
        {

        var streetBikesContents = db.Motorcycles.Where(m => m.Category.MotoCategory == "Street").Select(m => new MotorcycleDTO
            {
                ModelDto = m.Model,
                PriceDto = m.Price,
                BrandDto = m.Brand.Name,
                CategoryDto = m.Category.MotoCategory,
                DealersDto = m.Dealers.Select(d => d.Name).ToList()
            });

            var sportBikesContents = db.Motorcycles.Where(m => m.Category.MotoCategory == "Sport").Select(m => new MotorcycleDTO
            {
                ModelDto = m.Model,
                PriceDto = m.Price,
                BrandDto = m.Brand.Name,
                CategoryDto = m.Category.MotoCategory,
                DealersDto = m.Dealers.Select(d => d.Name).ToList()
            });

            var adventureBikesContents = db.Motorcycles.Where(m => m.Category.MotoCategory == "Adventure").Select(m => new MotorcycleDTO
            {
                ModelDto = m.Model,
                PriceDto = m.Price,
                BrandDto = m.Brand.Name,
                CategoryDto = m.Category.MotoCategory,
                DealersDto = m.Dealers.Select(d => d.Name).ToList()
            });

            var scooterBikesContents = db.Motorcycles.Where(m => m.Category.MotoCategory == "Scooter").Select(m => new MotorcycleDTO
            {

                ModelDto = m.Model,
                PriceDto = m.Price,
                BrandDto = m.Brand.Name,
                CategoryDto = m.Category.MotoCategory,
                DealersDto = m.Dealers.Select(d => d.Name).ToList()
            });

            var homeModel = new HomeModel
            {
                StreetBikesContents = streetBikesContents,
                SportBikesContents = sportBikesContents,
                AdventureBikesContents = adventureBikesContents,
                ScooterBikesContents = scooterBikesContents
            };

            return homeModel;
        }

    }
}

    }
```

**Models:**

*HomeModel class:*

```
 public class HomeModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<MotorcycleDTO> StreetBikesContents { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<MotorcycleDTO> SportBikesContents { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<MotorcycleDTO> AdventureBikesContents { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<MotorcycleDTO> ScooterBikesContents { get; set; }

    }
```

*Motorcycle class:*

```
//Database First Approach and Created by ADO.NET 
    public partial class Motorcycle
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Motorcycle()
        {
            this.Carts = new HashSet<Cart>();
            this.OrderDetails = new HashSet<OrderDetail>();
            this.Dealers = new HashSet<Dealer>();
        }
    
        public int MotorcycleId { get; set; }
        public string Model { get; set; }
        public double Price { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> BrandId { get; set; }
        public byte[] Image { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> CategoryId { get; set; }
    
        public virtual Brand Brand { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Cart> Carts { get; set; }
        public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Dealer> Dealers { get; set; }
    }
```

**DTO class:**

```
    public class MotorcycleDTO
    {
        public string ModelDto { get; set; }
        public double PriceDto { get; set; }
        public string BrandDto { get; set; }
        public string CategoryDto { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<string> DealersDto { get; set; }

    }
```

***Angular Side:***

**Model:**

*home-categorised-bikes.model.ts:*

```
export interface FromDTOContents{
    ModelDto: string;
    PriceDto: string;
    BrandDto: string;
    CategoryDto: string;
    DealersDto: string[];
}

export interface HomeModel{
sportBikesContents: FromDTOContents[];
streetBikesContents: FromDTOContents[];
adventureBikesContents: FromDTOContents[];
scooterBikesContents: FromDTOContents[];
}
```

**Service:**

*home-categorised-bikes.service.ts:*

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HomeCategorisedBikesService {

  Url = 'https://localhost:44377/api/Home';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  get(): Observable<HomeModel> {
    return this.http.get<HomeModel>(this.Url);
  }
}
```

**app.component.ts:**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'Home Page';

  constructor(private homeCategorisedBikesService: HomeCategorisedBikesService){}

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.getAllBikesContents();
}


getAllBikesContents(){
  this.homeCategorisedBikesService.get().subscribe(
    Response => {
      this.onHomeBikesContentsResponse(Response);
    }

  )
}

public sportBikesContentsvar: string[] = [];
public streetBikesContentsvar: string[] = [];
public adventureBikesContentsvar: string[] = [];
public scooterBikesContentsvar: string[] = [];

onHomeBikesContentsResponse(Response: HomeModel): void {
  Response.sportBikesContents.forEach((content: FromDTOContents) => {
  this.sportBikesContentsvar.push(`${content.BrandDto, content.CategoryDto, content.ModelDto, content.PriceDto, content.DealersDto}`);
  });
  
  Response.sportBikesContents.forEach((content: FromDTOContents) => {
  this.streetBikesContentsvar.push(`${content.BrandDto, content.CategoryDto, content.ModelDto, content.PriceDto, content.DealersDto}`);
  });

  Response.sportBikesContents.forEach((content: FromDTOContents) => {
  this.adventureBikesContentsvar.push(`${content.BrandDto, content.CategoryDto, content.ModelDto, content.PriceDto, content.DealersDto}`);
  });

  Response.sportBikesContents.forEach((content: FromDTOContents) => {
  this.scooterBikesContentsvar.push(`${content.BrandDto, content.CategoryDto, content.ModelDto, content.PriceDto, content.DealersDto}`);
  });
}


}
```

**app.component.html:**

```
<div class="container">
    <h3 class="textCenter">Soprt Bikes</h3>
    <div class="column" *ngFor="let c of sportBikesContentsvar">
        <h3>{{c}}</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="devideElement">
    <h3 class="textCenter">Street Bikes</h3>
        <div class="column" *ngFor="let c of streetBikesContentsvar">
            <h3>{{c}}</h3>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="devideElement">
           <h3 class="textCenter">Adventure Bikes</h3>
        <div class="column" *ngFor="let c of adventureBikesContentsvar">
            <h3>{{c}}</h3>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="devideElement">
          <h3 class="textCenter">Scooter Bikes</h3>
        <div class="column" *ngFor="let c of scooterBikesContentsvar">
            <h3>{{c}}</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

*Question:*

I want to display the c.model, c.brand, c.category, c.price, c.dealers which is an array of dealers for each motorcycle individually.

Please let me know if anything is unclear in the code or the question.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you clarify what problem you are encountering?

Answer (score 0):

The way you are declaring your `sportBikesContentsvar` and others are going to give you issue. It's better to define your object type `FromDTOContents[]`.

This way you will have access to all the object properties.

I'm posting one example, rest would be same

```
public sportBikesContentsvar: FromDTOContents[] = [];

onHomeBikesContentsResponse(Response: HomeModel): void {
  this.sportBikesContentsvar = Response.sportBikesContents;
}
```

Then in HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <h3 class="textCenter">Sport Bikes</h3>
    <div class="column" *ngFor="let c of sportBikesContentsvar">
        <h3>{{c.ModelDto}}</h3>
        <h3>{{c.PriceDto}}</h3>
        <h3>{{c.BrandDto}}</h3>
        <h3>{{c.CategoryDto}}</h3>
        <ng-container *ngFor="let dealers of c.DealersDto">
           <h3>{{dealers}}</h3>
        </ng-container>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Shivam but I still can't see the contents in the browser.